# Javascript - Scope and This

Tags: javascript, scope, this

I have some code below. the problem I don't understand is why I don't have to refer to 'children' object via this.children but then accessing the firstname or surname, i have to use this.firstname....

Please help me understand why.

```
function User(first, sur) {

    var firstName;
    var surName;
    var age;
    var children = [];
    this.firstName = first;
    this.surName = sur;

    this.getDisplayName = function() {
        return this.firstName + ' ' + this.surName;
    };

    this.getTotalLength = function() {

        return (this.firstName.length + this.surName.length);
    };

    this.displayFullName = function() {
        return (this.firstName + ' ' + this.surName);
    };

    this.changeMaidenname = function(newSurname) {
        if (newSurname)
        {
        this.surName = newSurname;
        }
    };

    this.addChild = function(childUser) {
        children.push(childUser);
    };

    this.numberOfChildren = function() {
        return children.length;
    };

    this.killChild = function(childUser) {
        children.forEach(function(item,index) 
        {
            if (item.firstName === childUser.firstName && item.surName === childUser.surName)
            {
                children.splice(index, 1);
            }
        }
    )
    };

};

module.exports.User = User
```

Comment: `firstName` and `this.firstName` are both extant identifiers, but you don't store a value in `firstName` (while you do store a value in `this.firsName`).

Comment: [Here](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html) you can read more about Module Pattern and [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/mastering-javascripts-this-keyword/) about this keyword

Answer (score 0):

In js,this keyword is used to create public variables whereas the var limits the scope of that variable to that particular function. :).You cant even access children object unless it is defined this.children=[]